# how to get the memebrs of a telegram group greater than 10000

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am getting only upto 10000 members when using telethon how to get more than 10000

I tried to run multiple times to check whether it is returning random 10000 members but still most of them are same only few changed that also not crossing two digits

Expected greater than 10000
but actual is 10000

Comment: You can only fetch 10000 members in megagroups with a given filter, this is a server-side limit.

Comment: create a database of many names and try to getting user by search those names and it will get more than 10000.

Answer (score 0):

there is no simple way. you can play with queries like 'a*', 'b*' and so on